# When should 吧 be used?

Tags: meaning

I understand that it is used at the end of a sentence to indicate suggestion, but I want to know what kinds of everyday situations warrant its use. I'd appreciate two or three examples. Also, does it have any other meanings?

Comment: It does have other meanings currently. 吧 is also a transliteration for the word **bar**. For example, 酒吧(wine bar), 百度贴吧(Baidu Saloon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this from an online dictionary:

> 吧 <助>
>
> ① 用在句末，表示恳求、提议、请求、命令等语气 [(used at the end of a sentence) indicating entreaty， suggestion， command， etc.]。如:派六个人不够吧，我的意见派十个人 / 你说给大家听听吧!
>
> ② 用在句末，表示同意、认可的语气 [indicating agreement or acknowledgment]。如:好吧，我一定去 / 就这样执行吧
>
> ③ 用在句末，表示疑问语气，带有揣度的意味 [indicating doubt]。如:他现在赞同了吧? / 你弄通了吧?
>
> ④ 用在句末，表示估量、推测语气 [indicating uncertainty]。如:他自己总该知道吧 / 老王会到这边来吧
>
> ⑤ 用在句中，表示停顿，带假设语气，并带有列举性质 [indicating a pause]。如:说吧，不好；不说吧，也不好

Answer (score 0):

It get some meaning like, let it be, or there is nothing I can do about it.

So if you are someone without too many opinion, you can use it almost at every end of sentences,  of cause you can stop when feeling people get bored of hearing it. But properly use of it will make others feel you are kind of a obedient person, easily get along with.

When in some phonetically translated words, it means bar. Not so hard to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

From experience: if you are the host of a restaurant meal and it has wound down and you have to move on then you might use 吧 for a suggestion that would be a question in English "Shall we go?"  But if you are the guest you would not make such a suggestion.  Fortunately people in China are very kind about foreigners getting points of etiquette wrong.

Answer (score 0):

我们也学学香港吧。

我们也闹一闹吧. 砸他几条商业街，雾霾就没有了。